# how to build rsocket-cpp for android ndk

Tags: c++, cmake, android-ndk, rsocket

can you please help to build `rsocket-cpp` library for `android ndk`.
The main problem was to include `folly` and `fmt` cmake projects so that `rsocket-cpp` will find it by itself with subsequent build and linking.

I was able to build rsocket-cpp with **INSTALLED** folly and fmt (meaning that rsocket-cpp could find and link them using `find_package` ). But the goal here is to create a build config so that `cmake` will build the rsocket-cpp for each of the android arm and x86
platforms just by *including* those dependencies as not built cmake projects

Comment: android ndk are built just by providing CMakeLists.txt, so you cannot use find_package that you installed on your system

Comment: rsocket-java is usable if you build with desugaring for Android 21+.  see https://github.com/rsocket/rsocket-demo-android-java8